# Histogram function

Tags: matlab, histogram

I am attempting to use the `histogram` function, however the following happens

```
EDU>> X = rand(5,1);
EDU>> histogram(X)

Undefined function 'histogram' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: `histogram` is only availabie in Matlab R2015b. You can use `hist` instead

Comment: Thank Luis. Appreciate it.

Comment: @LuisMendo Actually it was introduced in 2014b. Still probably your answer applies.

Comment: @neil in case you have matlab 2014b or later I would suggest you take a look at the variables and make sure there is no variable called histogram. Further, `help histogram` will print the help in case the function exist in your Matlab. Else it will print not found.